# ioredis pub/sub isn't listening, although it's connected

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

ioredis (v3.2.2) doesn't seem to be listening to my Redis pub/sub events, and I'm not sure why

I'm starting a server that listens to incoming messages, as:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');

redis.monitor(function (err, monitor) {
  monitor.on('monitor', function (time, args, source, database) {
    console.log(time + ": " + util.inspect(args));
  });
});

redis.psubscribe('*', function(err, count) {
  console.log("Listening to " + count + " channels.");
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// republish any data received
redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
  console.log("pmessage: " + message);
});
```

When I run the above, the log output shows:

```
Listening to 1 channels.
```

When I publish a message into the redis server's queue, the log output shows:

```
1531403083.031496: [ 'SELECT', '0' ]
1531403083.036594: [ 'RPUSH',
  'queues:myqueuename',
  '{## JSON message body ##}' ]
```

So: I'm clearly connected to the server and receiving data, but I don't understand:

1. Why the `monitor` callback isn't logging a PSUBSCRIBE or PUBLISH event, which is probably why:
2. The `pmessage` callback function isn't being fired

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did the `redis` object come from? I don't see it instantiated anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I'd forgotten to start the queue listener service, as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events